# load file contents into div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I want when click on specific link , the contents of a file will be loaded in a div. this works fine , but when I click on anothe one , I want contents of another file to loaded in ul element that is in that div,but it's not working .

this is what I made :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link2', function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("href");
  value=value.replace("#","");

   var linkName = {'href':value};

          $.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: 'pp.php',
  data :linkName,
  success: function(response){
      if(value=="login")
    $('#div1').html(response); 
      }
    });
     }); 

 $(document).on('click', 'a.link', function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("href");
  value=value.replace("#","");

   var linkName = {'href':value};
  // alert(value+"dd");
  $.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: 'make.php',
  data :linkName,
  success: function(response){

  $('#target').html(response);

      }
  });
  }) ;
```

html code:

```
<div id="div1">

<ul id="target">
 .
 .
 .
      </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are overwritting the contents of `#div1` (*with `$('#div1').html(response);`*) and so you remove the `ul` element. So when the next ajax call is made the `ul` cannot be found..

You can change your html to

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="ajaxresult"></div>
    <ul id="target"></ul>
</div>
```

and use `$('#ajaxresult').html(response);` instead of `$('#div1').html(response);`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the first ajax call overwrites the html inside `#div1` with `$('#div1').html(response)` so `#target` no longer exists when it comes to the second ajax call.

To get around it, you can change your html to:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<ul id="target"></ul>
```